# How to change the event at the press of a button in angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

everyone. 
I just started to learn Angular 6 and I have a question. I need that when a button is pressed, not only does the text of the button change, but the event changes, which should occur when the button is pressed. For example, the first click on the button will add the component to the memory, and the second click on this button will delete.

Here is my code from HTML:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="toggleEvent()">
        {{addToMemory ? 'Add to memory' : 'Delete from memory'}}
</button>
```

From TS:

```
addToMemory: boolean = true;

toggleEvent(): void {
 this.addToMemory = !this.addToMemory;
}
```

I have a function that will add the film to memory and delete.

```
add() {}
delete() {}
```

But I don’t understand how to switch a button by clicking between these functions. Please explain and help. Examples that I have found or do not work or it is not clear how to apply them.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm not answering your question, but why do you want to bind a different event to your html element ? Create a toggle function, which will call add or remove function regarding your boolean `addToMemory` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML part:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="toggleEvent()">
        {{addToMemoryFlag ? 'Add to memory' : 'Delete from memory'}}
</button>
```

---

Your TS part:

```
addToMemoryFlag: boolean = true;

toggleEvent() {

   this.addToMemoryFlag = !this.addToMemoryFlag;

   if(this.addToMemoryFlag) {
       this.addToMemory();
   } else {
       this.deleteFromMemory();
   }
}
```

> It is better better to differentiate names between `addToMemory` variable and `addToMemory()` method, change either the variable or the method's name.

Comment: Thank you, everything turned out to be so simple that I am ashamed of myself.

Comment: @Mark, Welcome and there is no shame in learning :) break a leg .

Answer (score 0):

**Template:**

```
<button class="btn" (click)="toggleEvent()">
        {{addToMemory ? 'Add to memory' : 'Delete from memory'}}
</button>
```

**Component:**

```
    addToMemory: boolean = true;

    toggleEvent(evt){
    this.addToMemory = !this.addToMemory;
    switch(evt.target.innerHTML.trim()){
      case 'Add to memory':
          this.Addtomemory();
          break;
      case 'Delete from memory':
          this.DeleteFrommemory();
          break;
    }
  }
```